# Can't make an auth Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authorization

I've a problem with Laravel. I did a login/register controller, register controller is adding users to database without any trouble, but when im trying to login, route to authenticatedusers doesn't work, still routing me to login page, I choose that as a main route for guest users.
Problem is atypical, because on my local machine all is working perfectly, but when I've copied my files to web server I have that problem. Someone have any idea?

**EDIT1:**

```
   public function login(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['mail' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    else if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));
}
```

It's the only change I've made to LoginController in App/Http/Controllers/Auth.

Comment: www.yoursite.com/public/index.php
use like this url

Comment: It's going to be hard to figure out what's going on without any code.

Comment: Do you have write permission for storage directory?

Comment: Adam A - What page u want me to paste as a code? Don't have idea which file should I paste

Comment: Yes, I have a permissions to storage directory.

Comment: rename server.php to index.php on root directory

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: do you upload middleware?

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded them.

Comment: saw me what you did in uploaded project

Comment: what do u excatly want?

Comment: you make any changes in auth controllerr?

Comment: added as an answer

Comment: but as i said all is working perfectly on my local server - MAMP.